# Как найти пропущенные числа в массиве?

Tags: php

Есть массив такого содержания:

```
array (
  0 => '1',
  1 => '2',
  2 => '3',
  3 => '4',
  4 => '5',
  5 => '6',
  6 => '7',
  7 => '8',
  8 => '9',
  9 => '11',
  10 => '12',
  11 => '13',
)
```

Нужно найти есть ли пропущенное значение в нем, например в этом, после **9** сразу идет **11** , то есть пропущено значение **10**

Буду благодарен за полезную информацию.

Comment: сравнивайте ключ и значение

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц как вариант) но хотелось бы более продвинутого решениея)

Comment: ну хорошо...запоминайте пред элеменет...и потом сравнивайте текущий с предыдущим запомненным и так в цикле...когда разница будет больше чем вам нужно то делаете "что-то"

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц зачем сравнивать ключ и значение? они собьются один раз, и дальше всегда будут различаться.

Comment: @teran задача была в том, чтобы узнать есть ли пропущенные или нет...если собьются один раз, то смело можно сказать что есть пропущенный и выходить из цикла

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц по моему заголовок вопроса говорит о несколько иной задаче. В противном случае, можно сравнить ключ и значение последнего элемента, вообще без всяких переборов.

Comment: @teran если честно, то что если одно число измениться и все дальше поплывет, то это в коде можно учесть, ведь шаг все равно не поменяется...так что сколько людей - столько и решений

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если размер массива достаточно большой, а предполагаемое число пропущенных элементов не велико, можно еще и такой вариант.

```
$data = [1,2,5,6,9,11];

$prev = current($data);
$result = array_reduce($data, function($c, $item) use (&$prev){
                    if($item - $prev > 1){
                        $c = array_merge($c, range($prev + 1, $item - 1));
                    }
                    $prev = $item;
                    return $c;
                }, []);
```

А если специфика задачи такова, что у нас очень большой массив и получается очень много пропущенных значений (и не очень большом числе самих пропущенных интервалов), что использование функции `range` тратит не оправдано много памяти, то как по [классическому примеру из справки по использованию генераторов](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.generators.overview.php) можем сделать следующее:

```
$result =  function($data){
                $prev = current($data);
                $ranges = array_reduce($data, function($c, $item) use (&$prev){
                            if($item - $prev > 1)   $c[] = [$prev+1, $item -1];
                            $prev = $item;
                            return $c;
                          }, []);
                foreach($ranges as list($l, $h)){
                     while($l <= $h) yield $l++;
                }
            };

foreach($result($data) as $x) echo $x, "\n";
```

в этом случае память будет тратится только на хранение пар значений, обозначающих края пропущенных отрезков.

Comment: `+` тоже подумал про генераторы после вашего вопроса в комментариях к моему ответу.

Comment: было бы еще хорошо сделать `static $prev = $item` но не судьба :)

Answer (score 6):

> *хотелось бы более продвинутого решения)*

```
$arr = [
    0 => '1',
    1 => '2',
    2 => '3',
    3 => '4',
    4 => '5',
    5 => '6',
    6 => '7',
    7 => '8',
    8 => '9',
    9 => '11',
    10 => '12',
    11 => '13'
];

$temp = range(reset($arr), end($arr));
$diff = array_diff($temp, $arr);

print_r($diff);
```

Comment: а если вдруг элементов будет не 10, а 10 млн?

Answer (score 1):

Не самое элегантное решение, но рабочее.

```
    $arr = [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11];
    $missedNumbers = [];

    foreach ($arr as $id => $number) {
        if (!isset($arr[$id + 1])) {
            continue;
        }

        if ($arr[$id + 1] - $number !== 1) {
            for ($i = 1; $i < $arr[$id + 1] - $number; $i++) {
                $missedNumbers[] = $arr[$id + 1] - $i;
            }
        }
    }
```

В цикле for находим недостающие числа.

$missedNumbers содержит следущее:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 10
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Мне нужно было найти первое пропущенное значение массива. Хотя в вопросе не указано именно первое, но и не указано, что все пропущенные.

Если нужно искать все пропущенные и оптимизировать расход памяти, то уже есть решение от [@teran](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/982027/217579). Только не забудьте про `sort()` вначале, если надо пройтись по-порядку. Я его протестировал - отлично работает.

В общем, сделал так:

```
function missedVal($A) {
    sort($A);
    foreach ($A as $key => $value) {

        if ($key!=0 && $value!=$A[$key-1] && $A[$key-1]!=$value-1) {
        return $A[$key-1]+1;
        break;
        }
    }
}
$A = [1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 7, 9, 3];
echo missedVal($A);
```

Возвращает - 5, func дошла до первого пропущенного и закончила работу.